# How do I create this textfield in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: textfield design]

Hey all, I designed this textfield in Sketch and basically used default iOS symbols to achieve it. However, the standard textfield component in Xcode is no where near this so I was wondering, how would I go about creating something like this?

Matthew

Comment: this is not a text field (usually). This is a table view

Comment: So I would need to embed a custom textfield in a table view?

Comment: you don't need. A table view already has a very similar design and components to achieve it

Comment: Where is the text field in the picture you posted? I see what looks like a grouped style table view containing cells setup with "value1" style (as used in the Settings app).

Answer (score 0):

You can create prototype cell, in that cell you can add label on left side and textfield on right side as subview. And change your textfield's 'Border style' to none.